# Prefill webform fields with alter hook

Tags: webforms, forms

I still have problems to access form fields programmatically, I want to prefill my textfield but it doesn't work:

```
function mymodule_form_webform_client_form_66_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form["submitted"]["title"]["#default_value"] = "blabla";
}
```

Even with mymodule_from_alter it doesn't work

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to access it using `$form["submitted"]` ?

Comment: no, just saw it on a tutorial...

Comment: To help find out why this isn't working, can you prove to yourself that this code is even being run? Two ways to do this: 1) use a xdebug-based debugger, e.g. Komodo IDE, PhpStorm/JetBrains Intellij or NetBeans. 2) with Devel module installed, insert some `dpm( $form );` debug code into this function and observe that it outputs debug on the page of the form. Once you have proven to yourself that this code is running then further investigation can occur. I will say that using `$form["submitted"]` etc, works for me in Webform 3.x Drupal 7, so this ought to work.

Comment: Also what version of WebForm? I'm using 3.x where the `$form["submitted"]` etc. approach works for me. If you are using Webform 4.x you might want to check if there are any differences from 3.x as to how to pre-populate. Another thing to do is clear your cache in Drupal (in the admin config pages of your site) or via command line using `drush cc all`